# Binomial sum involving power of $2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> Finding $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\cdot 2^{k+2}\binom{n}{k}$

Try: $$\int^{x}_{0}(1+x)^n=\int^{x}_{0}\bigg[\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\cdots\cdots +\binom{n}{n}x^n\bigg]dx$$

$$\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{n+1}=\binom{n}{0}x+\binom{n}{1}\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots \cdots +\binom{n}{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}2^{k+2}\binom{n}{k}}
> &=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+2}{k+2}2^{k+2}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\binom{n+2}{k}2^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left(3^{n+2}-1-2(n+2)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left(3^{n+2}-2n-5\right)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment*

- In (1) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{p+1}{q+1}=\frac{p+1}{q+1}\binom{p}{q}$ twice.
- In (2) we shift the index to start with $k=2$.
- In (3) we apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=(1+x)^n =\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}x^{k}\binom{n}{k} $$
Thus
$$g(x)=\int f(x) dx = \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{n+1}= \displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+1)}\cdot x^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}$$
Where the constant of integration was chosen so that $g(0)=0$. Also,
$$\int g(x) dx= \frac{(1+x)^{n+2}-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{x}{n+1}=\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\cdot x^{k+2}\binom{n}{k}$$
So that $$\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\cdot 2^{k+2}\binom{n}{k} =  \frac{(1+2)^{n+2}-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{2}{n+1}=  \frac{3^{n+2}-2n-5}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If
$$
f(x)=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\, x^{k+2}\binom{n}{k}
$$
then
$$
f''(x)=\sum^{n}_{k=0} x^{k}\binom{n}{k} = (1+x)^n
$$

Comment: I did not understand fully please explain me, thanks

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}}\, 2^{k + 2}{n \choose k}}} =
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\pars{{1 \over k + 1} - {1 \over k + 2}}\, 2^{k + 2}{n \choose k} \\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}\pars{t^{k} - t^{k + 1}}\dd t}\, 2^{k + 2}{n \choose k} =
4\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{2t}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
4\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}\pars{1 + 2t}^{n}\,\dd t =
\bbx{3^{n + 2} - 2n - 5 \over \pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1}}
\end{align}

> Set $\ds{x = 1 + 2t \iff t = {x - 1 \over 2}}$ such that
>   $\ds{4\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}\pars{1 + 2t}^{n}\,\dd t = \int_{1}^{3}\pars{3x^{n} - x^{n + 1}}\dd x}$.